# Java PrinterJob auto-orientation

Tags: java

I have an PDF what i want to print labels with PrinterJob. The problem is that the result is moved about 90 degrees, the printer is an Bixolon SLP-DX223. In the driversettings i have changed the label size in the main and default settings but there is no change on the print. If i print the pdf with the Acrobat Reader and the same settings the result ist perfekt but not with the PrinterJob print.

```
try {
     PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(file));
     PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService(printer);
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

     job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document, Orientation.PORTRAIT));
     job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
     job.setJobName(jobname);
     job.setCopies(copies);
     job.print();
     document.close();

} 
catch (PrinterException | IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Your setPageable method is set for portrait.  If you want landscape, you have to change the setPageable method.

Comment: Yes it is right, sorry i have posted the wrong code, i want to orientate automatical with 

```job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document, Orientation.AUTO));``` 

but it doesnt work...

Comment: the size of the document is exactly the size of the label in the settings...

Comment: You have to take page margins into account.  Your drawable area is not the entire page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer from @GilbertLeBlanc brings me to the result, the size of the paper was not definied, so i have use the following code:

```
double labelWidth = 50.8;           //width in mm
double labelHeigth = 25.4;          //height in mm

labelWidth = labelWidth / 0.353;    //calculate size
labelHeight = labelHeight / 0.353;  //calculate size

Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(labelWidth, labelHeight);
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

Book book = new Book();
book.append(new PDFPrintable(document), pageFormat, document.getNumberOfPages());

job.setPageable(book);              //job is the printerjob
```